# Indy 10.6.2 Proxy Server and browser error ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: delphi, http-proxy, indy10

I built proxy server application using (Delphi 10.4) listens to local port 8080, all browser request passes thro my **proxy server**, but in a lot of cases browser throws error in console **ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR** .

OnBeforeCommand Event Code

```
procedure TForm1.IdHTTPProxyServer1HTTPBeforeCommand(AContext: TIdHTTPProxyServerContext);
 var
SocksInfo: TIdSocksInfo;

  LURI: TIdURI;
  SSLClient: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  tempProxy  : TIdConnectThroughHttpProxy ;
  tempIO : TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL     ;

begin

    tempIO :=   TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(AContext.OutboundClient);
    tempProxy :=   TIdConnectThroughHttpProxy.Create(AContext.OutboundClient);

    tempProxy.Enabled := False;    //False to go direct internet
    tempProxy.Host := '127.0.0.1';    //   disabled for now
    tempProxy.Port := 8090 ;




  tempIO.SSLOptions.Mode       := sslmBoth;
  tempIO.SSLOptions.Method     := sslvSSLv23 ;
  tempIO.SSLOptions.SSLVersions:= [sslvSSLv2,sslvSSLv3,sslvTLSv1,sslvTLSv1_1,sslvTLSv1_2] ;
  tempIO.SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [];
  tempIO.SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 0;

  tempIO.ReadTimeout           := 5000;


  //Events
  tempIO.OnStatus              := StausChange;
  tempIO.OnStatusInfo          := StatusInfo;
  tempIO.PassThrough           := True;
  tempIO.OnVerifyPeer          := OnVerifyPeer ;

  tempIO.OnGetPassword :=  OnGetPassword ;
  tempIO.OnStatusInfoEx := OnStatusInfoEx ;



    tempIO.TransparentProxy           :=   tempProxy ;
    AContext.OutboundClient.IOHandler :=  tempIO;



end;
```

also I used the proper **SSL library** version **1.0.2.18**, so why this error raised repeatedly in browser console ?

Comment: *"in a lot of cases"* Please be more specific and provide examples of URLs that cause the issue.

Comment: Have you even searched for [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR) and read thru the results?

Comment: @Olivier I noticed it raised when ajax requests in background.

Comment: At this time, [Indy does not implement any support for HTTP/2](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/163), which uses a very different protocol on the wire than HTTP 1.x does. So `TIdHTTPProxyServer` will likely not work for you for HTTP/2 connections. You would have to use `TIdTCPServer` instead and manually implement the HTTP protocols yourself. Also, OpenSSL 1.0.2.12 (1.0.2l) is a bit old, the last version in the 1.0.2 series was 1.0.2u. If you want to use OpenSSL 1.1.x, use [this SSLIOHandler](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/pull/299) instead.